# accessing localized resources within a (to be) compiled control

Tags: c#, .net, localization, controls

i have a component project with controls for our site - that must now be localization-able. setting up the localization for the rest of the site was not a problem (we dropped `.resx` files into the `App_GlobalResources` directory; everything was hunky-dory), but i'm having a difficult time finding information on how to access resources locally within the component project.

- the `App_Local[/Global]Resources` folders don't want work - i can't "Add ASP.NET Folder" the way i can from the main project.
- when i generate it myself and drop .resx files into it, i can't figure out how to access them like i did in the site.

some abbreviated control code, contained entirely within `ThisWidget.cs` in the component project:

```
namespace site.shop {
  [ToolboxData("<{0}:ThisWidget runat=server></{0}:ThisWidget>")]
  public class ThisWidget : WebControl {
    protected override void CreateChildControls() {
      if (ChildControlsCreated) { return; }
      this.Controls.Clear();
      Label head = new Label();
      head.CssClass = "header";

      // fails: ThisWidget does not exist in namespace
      head.Text = System.Resources.ThisWidget.Label_head;
      // fails: can't find GetLocalResourceObject
      head.Text = new System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.GetLocalResourceObject("Label_head");
      // fails: can't find linked or embedded resources
      System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager();
      head.Text = Convert.ToString(rm.GetObject("Label_head"));

      this.Controls.Add(head);
    }
  }
}
```

and several variations with/out `new`, `System.Web.UI.TemplateControl`, etc...

i'd prefer not to have to compile this as a satellite assembly and then pull it back in (which seemed to be the other option), since the component project (a) has a number of related controls, and (b) *is* sort of a satellite dependency already, right? my hope was that i could drop the `.resx` files in, compile the `.DLL`, then the rest of the project can work.

**[edit]**
i feel like i'm getting closer to the answer, but i'm just not quite there yet...

any ideas? what am i missing?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, i was getting close - i popped open the `ThisWidget.Designer.cs` and found the correct parameters to call `ResourceManager()` with:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Components.App_LocalResources.ThisWidget", typeof(ThisWidget).Assembly);
head.Text = Convert.ToString(rm.GetObject("Label_head"));
```

seems to work like a charm. i also realized that since it is ignoring the specialness of `App_LocalResources`, i could put it anywhere, so i made a `/Resources/Resx/` directory and put the `.resx` files for each of the components' controls in with it. to update the call, this:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Components.Resources.Resx.ThisWidget", typeof(ThisWidget).Assembly);
```